# Understanding Mobility, steerability and manoeuvrability

Tags: mobile-robot, wheeled-robot

Determine the degrees of mobility, steerability and
manoeuvrability for each of the following:
i. tricycle;
ii. dynamically balanced robot with a single spherical
wheel;
iii. a differential drive robot / Segway.

I see M= 2, m=1 and s=1 for tricycle but don't understand why. Others not sure

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics*. This looks like a homework question, and on stack exchange, questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve/understand the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving/understanding it. Please edit your question to add this information and take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works. For advice on how to write a good question, see the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37).